Msal.net PublicClientApplicationBuilder AcquireTokenInteractive how to open in same browser tab?
I am using the MSAL.Net Microsoft.Identity.Client library to acquire authorisation to read a user's email inbox.
So I build a PublicClientApplication such as:
            pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
            .Build();

and than after, I issue the AcquireTokenInteractive command by:
                var result = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                .WithSystemWebViewOptions(new SystemWebViewOptions
                {
                    HtmlMessageError = "<p> An error occurred: {0}. Details {1}</p>",
                    BrowserRedirectSuccess = new Uri("https://www.my_auth_success_page.com")
                })
                .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(false)
                .ExecuteAsync();

What happens is: A new browser tab opens presenting the user the Microsoft log-in request.
After that, the original window gets redirected to the success page, while the window / tab used for authentication gets stale with a nasty error message: 'This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.'
I have the following issues:

Is there a way to have the authentication affair happening on the very same tab / window from where the AcquireTokenInteractive is called?
If not, How do I get past the problem of showing that 'This site can’t be reached' message? There is no way of having a controller action listening on the redirect Uri or setting up a HttpListener for a particular port, as then I get the following Exception: >


HttpListenerException:
Failed to listen on prefix 'http://localhost:8017/' because it
conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.

In other words: I cannot intercept the redirect call to gracefully handle the response.

Not specifying a redirect Uri is also not an option as this will result in another Exception not even getting to the authentication screen at all.
Which brings me to this question: Why on-earth do we need a redirect Uri at all? Since the authorisation results is already obtained from the AcquireTokenInteractive?

What am I missing here?

Based on the tags this seems to be a web application. You should use the Microsoft.Identity.Web library with that instead of MSAL: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-app-samples

@juunas. Thanks for your input. I have had a look at the link that you have sent. I think what that stuff is, is for having a user sign in into my website a a user. This is not exactly what I am looking for. My website could in theory be open to the public. All I want is that with a click of a button, a user does authorize my website to access his resources (in my case, gets authorized to access his IMap in order to read his emails) without being signed in into my website as a user.

You should use Microsoft Identity library just like what juunas said in the comment. Then you will have in Program.cs which EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi is used for injecting ITokenAcquisition service.
Nuget packages are <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.15.2" /> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.15.2" />
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

And in your Controllers, you can inject this service to generate access token if your app already signed in.
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;

    public HomeController(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
    {
        _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
    }
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {
        var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "User.Read" });
        return View();
    }
}


Thanks for your post. Please have a look at the comment I made to @juunas. I do not want a user to be authenticated to my website. I need him to Authorize my website to access his resources.

My website could in theory be open to the public. All I want is that with a click of a button, a user does authorize my website to access his resources --> Hi I'm afraid it's impossible. It's ok to make your app to be public, but the one-click-authorization operation must be the authentication. Users have to sign in first so that your app could help generate access token. Azure AD provides several flows for authorization and generate access token. For web app, we usually use auth code flow which requires user sign in.\

Thanks. User indeed have to go through an authentication process. But not on my website. My website initiates a authorization request upon which Msal redirects the user to a page from Microsoft where the user signs-in and conforms my app can access his resources - in my case: reading his emails via Imap.

MSal Authorisation Page

Pls bear with me sharing my understanding here, and correct me if I'm wrong. According to your description, it look like you want to have a public app providing websites for users. And maybe there will be a menu inside your website which providing the entrence for users to view their resource. For Azure, it provides Microsoft Graph API for users to accecss their resources but it requires users to get authenticated first. What we could see about "authentication" is an redirection to sign in page of Microsoft Identity platform.

To achieve this feature in a web app, we couldn't compose a url then use http.get(url) or window.open(url) to achieve the redirection, we have to use MSAL SDK and it's Microsoft.Identity.Web for .net core web app, otherwise we'll get unexpected error just like what you've met. When we use this library, we could add [Authorize] attribute on Controller or controller action method to make sure users have to sign in first then they could visit it. The policy I defined in my post above is not required for your scenario.

If you do have such a menu in your web app, you might add my configurations into your app and comment options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));, then add [Authorize] attribute to your action method for that menu, so that your app won't require users to sign in except they click that button,

But assuming what you have is an web API, then my codes is not suitable for you. Web api is a daemon application so that we could use client credential flow or on-behalf-of flow. Client credential flow doesn't require a user to sign in, it  authenticate the application itself so that the application could help to query any users' resource in your tenant when the application has enough permission. On-behalf-of flow also requires a user to sign in ahead and generate an access token to call the api, and the API used the authorized access token to generate another token.
